# Creating list of all pairwise comparisons within data frame in R

Tags: r

From a data frame in R that has X Y coordinates (see example) I would like to add to rows (final X and final Y) to show all possible pairwise comparisons between the two.

```
dt = data.frame(X = seq(1, 5, by=1), Y = seq(1, 5, by=1))
```

This is the final goal but there should be a row for every possible combination of x, y and final_x, final_y

[image]

Comment: Why don't you have the x and y coordinates in separate columns as numeric, instead of having them merged together as a string?

Comment: As I thought it would be easier to work with 1 column instead of 2? However could easily have two separate columns

Comment: Definitely easier to have the two coordinates in separate columns, as numeric.

Comment: Agree easier to have x and y in separate columns, would recommend reviewing lessons on [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html).

Comment: Thanks - I have edited above

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expand.grid`:

```r
eg <- expand.grid(final_Y = 1:5, Y = 1:5, final_X = 1:5, X = 1:5)[,c(4,2,3,1)]
head(eg, n=20)
#    X Y final_X final_Y
# 1  1 1       1       1
# 2  1 1       1       2
# 3  1 1       1       3
# 4  1 1       1       4
# 5  1 1       1       5
# 6  1 2       1       1
# 7  1 2       1       2
# 8  1 2       1       3
# 9  1 2       1       4
# 10 1 2       1       5
# 11 1 3       1       1
# 12 1 3       1       2
# 13 1 3       1       3
# 14 1 3       1       4
# 15 1 3       1       5
# 16 1 4       1       1
# 17 1 4       1       2
# 18 1 4       1       3
# 19 1 4       1       4
# 20 1 4       1       5
nrow(eg)
# [1] 625
```

I defined the columns out of order and reordered them simply to match the ordering of your expected output. One could easily do `expand.grid(X=,Y=,final_X=,final_Y=)` and leave off the `[,c(...)]` and the effective results would be the same but in a different row-order.

Comment: Fleaf, does this do what you expect?